# Is it possible to change navigator.appname in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

My  college web kiosk has this naive problem that it can only be opened in I.E..
here's the code i recently found out

> **if (navigator.appName=='Netscape' || navigator.appName=='Firefox' || navigator.appName=='Google Chrome' || navigator.appName=='Safari' || navigator.appName=='Opera' || navigator.appName=='Opera' ) 
>       { 
>       alert('This website can only be viewed with Internet Explorer');
>       window.history.go(-1); 
>   //  window.history.forward(1);
>       }**

Is there any method to spoof the navigator.appname property in chrome ?
thanks

Comment: Find a Google Chrome addon/extension that allows you to spoof it

Answer (score 0):

You can change the useragent from the google chrome inspector tools.
Press F12 and open the chrome inspector
Click on the settings icon (should be in bottom right corner)
In the page go to overrides -> And from there select your useragent as IE 9 / 8 / 7

Now when you check navigator.appName it will show your Netscape.

Comment: I want to change the navigator.appname to microsoft internet explorer
how do i override netscape in chrome ?

Comment: i guess chrome only allows you to change the userAgent string and not the appname. you can use an extension like IE Tab https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en which allows you to open a website inside an IE tab